# Galois group of $x^3+2$ and intermediate subfields

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

the splitting field of $x^3+2$ is $E=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2},i\sqrt{3}$) and I know the $Gal(E:\mathbb Q)$ has six elements which is isomorphic to $S_3$.

How to find all intermediate subfields using the correspondence between subgroups and subfields.

Comment: The zeros of $x^3+2$ are the negatives of those of $x^3-2$, so, as you observed, they share the splitting field. And determining the intermediate fields of that is a standard exercise in Galois theory. I like to think it has been done on this site a few times. Have you searched?

Comment: I know how to find the intermediate fields of $x^3-2$. Are they the same? since they share the same splitting field . Is it that true in general  for any polynomial $x^n+a$ has the same Glaois of $x^n_a$

Comment: Good! $x^n-a$ and $x^n+a$ share the same splitting field (and hence also the Galois group and the collection of intermediate fields) if and only if $n$ is an odd integer. This is because then the roots of one are the negatives of the other.